# CSS HTML Positioning

Tags: html, css

So,

i'm guessing this has been asked before but im realy missing something here which i've been starring myself dead at for the last hour.

I've got a container with two divs, position relative and absolute since i want them to stack. The stacking part works. However, this container, the #mockupcontainer, needs to be inside the #what-container-inner which i cant seem to get to work. At the moment it just stops the #what-container-inner and placed the #mockupcontainer after it. My jsfiddle illustrates perfect whats going wrong. I hope someone can help me on this one.

https://jsfiddle.net/rvq41vaf/

CSS:

```
#what-container-outer {
  background-color: #ececec;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#what-container-inner {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.mockupcontainer{
  position: relative;
}
#pin-mockup{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#pin-mockup-site1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:11;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
  <div id="what-container-outer">
    <div id="what-container-inner">
      sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf<br>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
      <div id="trigger-mockup"></div>
      <div class="mockupcontainer">
        <div id="pin-mockup">
          <img src="image2" class="img-responsive" alt="Realiseren">
        </div>
        <div id="pin-mockup-site1">
          <img src="image1" class="img-responsive" alt="Realiseren">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Kind Regards,
Donny.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't illustrate at all what's going wrong, unfortunately. What's going wrong? How are these divs supposed to look?

Comment: The lion and polarbear container, "#mockupcontainer", needs to be inside the "#what-container-inner".  Not after it. It should be realy simple but I just don't see it.

Comment: Question is not clear, please explain more.

Comment: Edited question with: "The stacking part works. However, this container, the #mockupcontainer, needs to be inside the #what-container-inner which i cant seem to get to work. At the moment it just stops the #what-container-inner and placed the #mockupcontainer after it."

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want them to overlap the text? Do you want the dimensions of the gray box to extend below the picture? `position: absolute` causes them to be removed from the flow. Did you try `position: relative`? Maybe setting the `height` of `#what-container-inner` to something? It's hard to tell what you're asking, so I'm just taking some shots at things that might affect it.

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/rvq41vaf/1/

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your two image-containing divs (`pin-mockup` and `pin-mockup-site1`) positioned absolutely, they are pulled out of the flow and the enclosing divs no longer leave room for them. The solution is to set the larger one to `position: relative` so that the enclosing div does make room for it. Setting `top:0` on the second (absolutely positioned) div brings it to the top of the enclosing div.

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rvq41vaf/1/)

[See also the MDN docs on the `position` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)